# How to Throw Multilingual Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multilingual

I have a multilingual web application, where I use a resource file in the frontend to display the different text.

*I followed this approach http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/586948/ASP-NET-Website-and-Csharp-with-Multi-Language*

Is there a way where the exception handling done in the backend throws exceptions according to the current language selected?

Comment: In my opinion the "users" of exceptions are the developers, not he real users. I would  never localize exception messages. Most of the time users do not care about technical details. They just need to know that something failed and what their options are.

Comment: I get your point. But leaving apart system exceptions, is there a way to translate application exceptions?

Comment: @MartinLiversage best way for validation is with custom exceptions ! Yes you can do that

Comment: @mybirthname So you catch the custom exception and change the outputted text from the frontend?

Comment: Yes you catch the Exception, but never catch all the Exception just only specific ones needed in your cases. In the past I catch like this DBConcurrency exception and re throw custom exception with message. This should be done for specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need CustomException which inherit `Exception` for this.(Be aware never catch all the exceptions only the exception needed for your case, I just wrote you an example. If you catch all the exception you can lose specific information when something go wrong on productive server. Like I said in the past I used it for DBConcurrencyException)

**Business Object logic**

```
try
{
    //some code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   CustomException newEx = new CustomException();
   newEx.Message = "Translate Multilanguage String depending of the user culture"
   throw newEx;
}
```

**UI-part aspx.Page**

```
try
{
    //some code which calls the BO logic with try/catch
}
catch(CustomException ex)
{
    Label1.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

How to use this for validation purpose:

```
if(myValue < 5)
   throw new CustomException("Value should not be under 5");
```

Comment: However, in what way can I use the resource file on the BO logic?

Comment: @JEPAAB I don't know that, I don't use resource files.